# Android application dies when closing InputStream

Tags: android, inputstream

I have an OpenGL game with two images, one is a texture atlas, and one is a single image. When I try to open the single one to an OpenGL object the application dies when closing it.
The code:

```
        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(texture);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
                is = null;
                Log.i("log", "try");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("log", "Catch");
            }
        }
```

It decodes the InputStream, but it steps into the catch after closing. I really can't understand what is the problem. Opening and closing InputStreams with the other texture works fine.

Comment: I bet there are some good clues to the source of the problem in the stack trace, try logging the stack trace: Log.i("log", "Catch", e);

Comment: Is this happening on the emulator ?

Comment: With "e" nothing happens, LogCat only writes out "Catch".
R.daneel.olivaw: no, it happens both on the emulator and on the phone (Vodafone 845). After closing, steps in the catch, comes out the many DEBUG message in LogCat and application dies.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code to print a stacktrace

```
final Writer result = new StringWriter();
final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
ex.printStackTrace(printWriter);
String stacktrace = result.toString();
Log.i("log", "Catch" + stacktrace);
```

then hopefully you will have your answer :)

Comment: I have put my texture into my texture atlas, but maybe tomorrow I will try it, and see what is says, thanks!